# Reference to the div by its class name at any level

Tags: jquery, html

[image]I am trying to get value in the innermost divs with classname 'myData'. These divs are loaded dynamically and it could be at any level of nesting. The outermost div has a id "main". This is what I have tried so far and it only gives me divs' classanames  who are immediate children of main div.

UPDATE: I need to get reference to fc-event-time div highlighted in the image.

```
$('#main div').each(function() {
alert($(this).text());
```

});

Thanks,

Comment: You said "innermost"... do you mean like this? http://jsbin.com/wihu/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add .myData to the end:

```
$('#main div.myData').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
```

Here is a jsfiddle as a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/66psS/

***======= Update from comments =======***

At what stage are you calling this .each() function? Is it in the document.ready? Is this data being loaded via AJAX and may not exist when the .each() runs?

```
// Means run this when the document is ready...
$function(){
    $('#main div.myData').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
});
```

My bet is that the data doesn't exist yet on the page when this is being executed.

Comment: Thanks Jay, your code works well in fiddle. But for some reason I always get 0 in my page. please see the updated question.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Updated post a bit with some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do:

```
$('#main div.myData').each(function() {
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: If you have more than one element with an id of main, you are doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#main .myData').each(function() {
 alert($(this).text());
});
```

Update: If other elements have `.myData` class too:

```
$('#main div.myData').each(function() {
 alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This will not restrict the results to a ***div*** with that class name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screen shot you added to your question, it looks like you can simply use:

```
$(".fc-event-time").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

to generate a list of divs that have this class name.  If you want to scope it only to a certain hierarchy, you can qualify the selector with whatever parent you want to limit the scope to, but that is not required:

```
$("#main .fc-event-time").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

If this content is dynamically added, then you MUST run this query AFTER the content is inserted into the DOM.  How you work the timing if the content is dynamically added depends upon how it is added and what events you have that you can trigger your query from.

If this content is in the original HTML of the document, then you must run the query after the DOM has been loaded.  You can either place your javascript at the end of the `<body>` or you can use jQuery to wait for the DOM to load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main .fc-event-time").each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```